# How can I use a custom type as key for a map in C++?

Tags: c++, struct, key, operator-overloading, stdmap

I am trying to assign a custom type as a key for `std::map`. Here is the type which I am using as key:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(std::string s) : foo_value(s){}

    bool operator<(const Foo& foo1) {   return foo_value < foo1.foo_value;  }

    bool operator>(const Foo& foo1) {   return foo_value > foo1.foo_value;  }
    
    std::string foo_value;
};
```

When used with `std::map`, I am getting the following error:

```
error C2678: binary '<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Foo' (or there is no acceptable conversion) c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional 143
```

If I change the `struct` to the one below, everything works:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(std::string s) : foo_value(s)   {}

    friend bool operator<(const Foo& foo,const Foo& foo1) { return foo.foo_value < foo1.foo_value;  }

    friend bool operator>(const Foo& foo,const Foo& foo1) { return foo.foo_value > foo1.foo_value;  }
    
    std::string foo_value;
};
```

Nothing changed, except that the operator is overloaded as *friend*. Why does my first code not work?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I suspect you need

```
bool operator<(const Foo& foo1) const;
```

Note the `const` after the arguments, this is to make "your" (the left-hand side in the comparison) object constant.

The reason only a single operator is needed is that it is enough to implement the required ordering. To answer the abstract question "does a have to come before b?" it is enough to know whether a is less than b.

Comment: Can you go into more detail?  Why do you only need operator< and not operator== or operator>?

Comment: because you can derive operator> and operator== from operator<.

`(b < a)` implies `(a > b)`, so there's operator>.
and, `(!(a < b) && !(b < a))` means that a isn't less than b nor greater than b, so it must be equal to b.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably looking for const member operators (whatever the correct name is).
This works (note const):

```
bool operator<(const Foo& foo1) const { return foo_value < foo1.foo_value;}
```

EDIT: deleted `operator>` from my answer as it was not needed (copy/paste from question) but it was attracting comments :)

Note: I'm 100% sure that you need that **const** because I compiled the example.

Comment: Funny stackoverflow shows previous answer 10 minutes ago but when I submit my answer there wasn't any yet ... hence the same answer

Comment: Since object is constant const function would be required.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers already solve your problem, but I'd like to offer an alternative solution. Since [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) you can use a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead of defining `operator<` for your `struct`. (`operator>` is not needed for your map to work.) Providing a lambda expression to the constructor of a map has certain advantages:

- I find the declaration of a lambda expressions to be simpler and less error-prone than that of operators.
- This approach is especially useful if you can't modify the `struct` that you want to store in your map.
- You can provide different comparison functions for different maps that use your `struct` as key.
- You can still define `operator<` differently and use it for a different purpose.

As a result, you can keep your `struct` as short as follows:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(std::string s) : foo_value(s) {}
    std::string foo_value;
};
```

And your map can then be defined in the following way:

```
int main() {
    auto comp = [](const Foo& f1, const Foo& f2) { return f1.foo_value < f2.foo_value; };
    std::map<Foo, int, decltype(comp)> m({ {Foo("b"), 2}, {Foo("a"), 1} }, comp);
    // Note: To create an empty map, use the next line instead of the previous one.
    // std::map<Foo, int, decltype(comp)> m(comp); 

    for (auto const &kv : m)
        std::cout << kv.first.foo_value << ": " << kv.second << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> a: 1
> b: 2

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/haByIO)