# Custom Key for std::map<>

Tags: c++, struct, key, stdmap

I am trying to use the following `struct` as a custom key for `std::map`:

```
struct ActionId {
        // ENCAPSULATED MEMBERS
    private:
        size_t _id;
        static size_t _root;
        static size_t incrementedRoot() {
            return (_root += 1);
        }

        // INTERFACE
    public:
        ActionId() :
            _id(incrementedRoot()) { }
        ActionId(const ActionId& that) :
            _id(that._id) { }
        ActionId& operator=(const ActionId& that) {
            this->_id = that._id;
            return *this;
        }
        bool operator==(const ActionId& that) const {
            return this->_id == that._id;
        }
        bool operator!=(const ActionId& that) const {
            return this->_id != that._id;
        }
        bool operator<(const ActionId& that) const {
            return this->_id < that._id;
        } 
};
```

The following dictionary is a member of a separate `InputManager` class:

```
std::map<ActionId, std::set<sf::Keyboard::Key>> _keyBindings;
```

which is accessed in this member function:

```
std::set<sf::Keyboard::Key> InputManager::keysBoundTo(ActionId action) const {
    return _keyBindings[action];
}
```

Unfortunately, the function is throwing this compiler error:

> error C2678: binary '[' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type '`const std::map<Game2D::ActionId,std::set<sf::Keyboard::Key,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<_Kty>>,std::less<Game2D::ActionId>,std::allocator<std::pair<const Game2D::ActionId,_Ty>>>`' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

According to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/906244/3991688), the `operator<()` member of `ActionId` with `const` qualification should be sufficient to make it a custom map key, while [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6573225/3991688) says that all I need is to make `ActionId` copiable and assignable.  Clearly, my struct meets both of these criteria, so why won't `InputManager::keysBoundTo()` compile?

Comment: You are looking at all the wrong places. `map::operator[]` isn't `const`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index operator (the "[]") is a non-const member function of std::map.  Whereas, you have clearly indicated that `keysBoundTo` is a const member.

Rewrite `keysBoundTo` as

```
std::set<sf::Keyboard::Key> InputManager::keysBoundTo(ActionId action) const
{
    auto it = keyBindigs_.find(action);
    if ( it == keyBindings_.end() )
        return std::set<sf::Keyboard::Key>();
    else
        return it->second;
}
```

Notice that I renamed your member variable to have a trailing underscore.  Do not use identifiers with leading underscores.

Comment: Wow, never would've thought of that.  So are you saying that, in this case, operator[] is returning a modifiable `std::set<>&` object, and there is no conversion from that to `const std::set<>&`?  I find that rather surprising.  Your code compiles just fine though, thanks :)  Also, why don't you recommend leading underscores?

Comment: No, it is not to do with the value (the set in this case) being modifiable or non-modifiable.  As I said in my answer, std::map's operator[] is a *non-const* member.  It _could_ modify the map (insert the key corresponding to the input if it is not found).

Comment: Identifiers with leading underscores are reserved by the implementation (i.e., the compiler writer).

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps That's a simplification. `_Ugly` and `__ugly` are reserved everywhere. `_ugly` is reserved only in the global namespace