# which datastructure or stl to be used to save a pair with a value?

Tags: c++, stl

I have a data like

```
**"London","Paris" -> 10
"New York","Japan" -> 100
"London","Japan" -> 200**
..
```

How to save pair with value using STL? As Map only allow key and value, not extra key.

I can save key with extra object which will hold the 2 values.

```
 map < string, Object>
```

But then i have to go through an extra step of parsing the object and it will be an overhead.

Even i can do my work using linked list. But is there any other efficient way to save it and access it? Or i am thinking in correct direction? I am new to STL.

Comment: `map< pair<std::string, std::string>, int >` perhaps

Comment: @M.M trivial as it may seem to experienced users of the STL, it's not obvious to beginners that std::pair<> is comparable. This should be an answer

Comment: @RichardHodges I couldn't remember either TBH, but if someone responded saying it wasn't, I was going to suggest how to make a custom comparator

Comment: "London","Paris" the key and 10 the value?

Comment: Since you are new to STL, it would be worth learning how to have custom Keys in associative containers.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906244/custom-types-as-key-for-a-map-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either an `std::map` (as noted by M. M.) or an `std::unordered_map` of `std::pair<std::string, std::string>`s to `int`s.

The `std::map` is easy - simply use `std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, int>`. The standard library already knows how to compare pairs.

If you don't need ordering, though, you might be better off with a hash-based dictionary. Borrowing from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590656/error-for-hash-function-of-pair-of-ints), first define this:

```
struct pairhash {
public:
    template <typename T, typename U>
    std::size_t operator()(const std::pair<T, U> &x) const
    {
        return std::hash<T>()(x.first) ^ std::hash<U>()(x.second);
    }
};
```

(see comment below by Tony D for an even better version.)

Now you can use `std::unordered_map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, int, pairhash>`.

---

Be sure to include the appropriate headers, also (e.g., `<map>` and `<unordered_map>`, respectively). For the unordered version, you should also make sure you're building in c++11 settings.

Comment: Thanks. I think as answered by M.M and you, will work for me. i need to scratch more my head towards STL. But, i got my directions where to move ahead.

Comment: `std::hash<T>()(x.first) ^ std::hash<U>()(x.second);` is awfully collision prone - every `pair` where `first == second` will hash to 0, and every pair `(a, b)` will collide with `(b, a)`.  Those circumstances may not apply to the OP's data, but in general - if stopping short of `boost::hash_combine` - even `std::hash<T>()(x.first) ^ (std::hash<U>()(x.second) << 3) ^ (std::hash<U>()(x.second) >> 2);` is *much* better.

Comment: @TonyD Many thanks - updated to reference your comment.